# The ListView Items in my navigation drawer are there but I can't see the list

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

The list is there and it goes to whatever activity I send it to but the list the names on the list don't show. I've changed the color of the font and the drawer background and it doesn't show. The item gets highlighted alright and it redirects to the proper activity as it should but there's nothing written in the drawer.

activity_main:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/menu_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml:

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listMenu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuArray);
    dLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu_drawer);

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, listMenu));
```

Comment: this works just fine for me. Maybe you are using the wrong list item file: drawer.xml and in your Activty you are referencing R.layout.drawer_list_item?

Comment: yes, I copied your code without any changes and tried it on android 4.0 and 4.2.

Comment: I figured it out and answered my own question. Thanks!

Comment: ok, the missing file ;-)

Comment: I know, should have included that... why am I so stubborn. The error is always in the place you think can be no error. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had set my array like this:

```
<item name="section" value="Section"/>
```

when I should have done this:

```
<item name="section">Section</>
```